# Prevent User with Read Permission to have access to site content and site usage

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-pages, sharepoint-permissions

I have created a group and assign the Read permission to it. I modified the the Read permission to the below to prevent the site usage and site content access.

List Permissions:

1. View Items
2. Open Items

Site Permissions:

1.View Pages

2.Use Remote Interfaces

3.Open

Now the permission work perfectly my users do not have access to site usage and content. But my navigation on my home page does not show up. Basically the navigation is just 3 links pointing to three views of the same list. I do get access to the list when i manually visit the list thought.

I am using modern pages and list. When i set the permission "VIew application pages" my navigation come back but then i get the issue of my users being able to access site usage and site content

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default **READ** permission and remove only **View Application Pages** permission.

It will remove user’s access to both Site Contents and Site usage page, and throws `Access Denied` error when being accessed.

Comment: i mentioned this in the question. When i do this my navigation disappear on my home page. It is just 3 links pointing to 3 different views of the same list. If i manually navigate to the list it works, my user do have access to it. Interesting fact here is when the user reach the list, the navigation appear here.

Comment: @keshav If you are using the Navigation (with publishing features enabled in this site) then that is the expected behavior. List views access is included in the `View Application Pages` permission. User will not have access to lists by default, unless you give them unique permission in the list that includes this permission. This works fine for Quick Launch.

Comment: They have read permission on my site ,and my list inherit the permission of the site  but the each list item have unique permissions. Publishing feature is not enable on the site collection nor at site level. On the List item they have Edit permission which do include this permission. Some of the list item have edit permission and some Read. Is this the cause? Should all the item have edit permission in this case which in my case will eventually happens after am done setting the permission of each item .....OR create a unique permissions to share the list instead of inheriting the Read permiss

Comment: This is what i did i share the site to the user with read permission(View Application Pages not enabled). Then i created a similar permission level as Read but with Application Pages Enabled which i called Restricted Read. I stop inheriting the list from parent and share the list with the user with this permission. But again i can see the users getting access to site content

Comment: @keshav Sorry for the late reply. The “View Application Pages” permission is included in all permission levels by default. I’ve made a quick test with the default View Only permission with this permission removed. Here is my setup for Quick Launch: I have Site Contents as a link and entrances to lists as sub links. 
User has View Only permission in one of the lists, and the custom permission at site level. The link to Site Contents and the sub link to the list (which he has unique permission) are visible to this user, but he gets access denied when clicking on Site Contents on Quick Launch.